# Why isn't Coleridge's line about trochees missing an unstressed syllable?

Tags: poetry, meter, samuel-taylor-coleridge

Samuel Coleridge wrote this really fun poem, *Metrical Feet: Lesson for a Boy*, that names and gives examples of the various types of metric feet. I've included a copy and scanned the poem to make the various feet clearer.

> **Tro**chee **trips** from **long** to **short**;
>   From **long** to **long** in **so**lemn **sort**
>   **Slow Spondee stalks; strong foot!** yet **ill** able
>   **Ev**er to **come** up with **dac**tyl tri**sy**llable.
>   I**am**bics **march** from **short** to **long**;—
>   With a **leap** and a **bound** the swift **An**apæsts **throng**;

I'm curious about the first line, which is supposedly an example of trochees. On one hand, there are three trochees in the first line ("**Tro**chee **trips** from **long** to"). On the other hand, the first line isn't exactly trochaic meter--compare it to actual trochaic meter such as "Double, double toil and trouble /  Fire burn and caldron bubble." It's missing an unstressed syllable at the end of the line. Rather, [the first line is acephaleous iambic tetrameter](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/catalectic-trochaic-tetrameter-or-acephaleous-iambic-tetrameter-scanning-kubla).

Why doesn't Coleridge omit the final unstressed syllable from his line about trochees, which makes it not quite trochaic meter? For every other line (iambic, dactyl, etc) he uses exactly the meter associated with that type of metric foot. (This is kind of the point of the poem.)

Comment: What is your basis for concluding that it is acephalous iambic rather than catalectic trochaic?

Comment: @verbose because the next line is iambic--see the linked answer [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/catalectic-trochaic-tetrameter-or-acephaleous-iambic-tetrameter-scanning-kubla).

Comment: But that answer is about a completely different poem whose overall prosody is largely iambic.  It’s contextual. In this context the line is clearly intended as trochaic.

Comment: @verbose either way, there is no functional difference between the two: acephalous iambic sounds exactly the same as catalectic trochaic. What I'm asking is why is it acephalous iambic/catalectic trochaic instead of just trochaic. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Then it’s an easy answer. Trochee in English is typically catalectic because feminine endings.

Comment: @verbose I would love to read that answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

It was very difficult to find analysis let alone explanation of this poem so I apologise for any unsupported reasoning.

---

It *is* in trochaic tetrameter, because there are four [trochees](https://www.britannica.com/art/trochee) in the first line, as you highlighted in your copy (numbers indicate stress number):

> **TRO**(1)chee **TRIPS**(2) from **LONG**(3) to **SHORT**(4)

With scansion symbols it looks like this (- = stressed, ˘ = unstressed):

[image: Trochee stresses]

There are four stresses to the line (resulting in a tetrameter) each with the stress on the first, not the following, syllable (resulting in trochaic meter).

Iambic tetrameter is the reverse of trochaic tetrameter as the unstressed syllable comes before the stressed syllable. If it was iambic, the stresses would look like this:

> tro**CHEE** trips **FROM** long **TO** short

If you try to say the line with the stresses like this, it is really awkward. The trochaic tetrameter just fits better.
(Using iambic stressing on the line would also only result in three stresses making it iambic trimeter.)

It is in fact the same rhythm and stress pattern and meter, as the lines from *Macbeth*:

> **DOU**ble, **DOU**ble, **TOIL** and **TROU**ble.
>
> **FI**re **BURN** and **CAUL**dron **BU**bble.

The stress is on the first syllables and there are four stresses to each line. **However**, there is an extra unstressed syllable at the end of these lines when compared to S. T. Coleridge's poem's line. Nevertheless, it is the stressed syllables which define the meter and the missing unstressed syllable at the end of the S. T Coleridge line therefore makes the meter **catalectic trochaic tetrameter** (a [catalectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalectic) line is a metrically incomplete line of verse, lacking a syllable at the end or ending with an incomplete foot).
In the question you linked, it can be deduced that catalectic trochaic tetrameter and acephalous iambic tetrameter are somewhat difficult to separate; however, since this poem's form is meant to mirror the content, it is (catalectic) trochaic tetrameter.

The next line of the poem does not correspond with the first but corresponds with the third because is it describing [spondees](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spondee):

> From long to long in solemn sort

The definition for spondees is: a metrical foot consisting of two long or stressed syllables, which the line is describing with "long and long". The second line is also separate from the first with a semicolon at the end of the first, so they are definitely unrelated. The real question is why is the second line not in spondees? I cannot find any explanations for this, apart from that the stressed 'o' sounds in the line act to emphasise the spondees in the next line. Also, in old copies of S. T. Coleridge's poems, where the lines are scanned, line 2 is sometimes left unscanned (along with the second part of the poem, which deviates away from describing meter and addresses his son), so maybe it is not meant to have a definite meter (sort does make a rhyming couplet with short so that could be the reason for this rogue line). Regardless of line 2, the line about trochees is definitely in catalectic trochaic meter.

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. Everything else in the poem: the dactyl, the iambic, etc. don't have a dropped syllable. I'm asking why the line with trochees has a dropped syllable, given that the other lines don't have this.

Comment: "Also, in old copies of S. T. Coleridge's poems" if you could tell me where to find this material I would appreciate it, it ounds interesting.

Comment: @Hamlet But isn't that the definition of catalectic trochaic meter?

Comment: that's not what I'm disputing. Why is it catalectic trochaic meter instead of just trochaic meter? That's what the question is asking.

Comment: @Hamlet Sure, [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=isYNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA306&dq=trochee+trips+from+long+to+short&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKpvvN15jYAhXkJMAKHWOgD74Q6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=trochee%20trips%20from%20long%20to%20short&f=false) edition demonstrates it.

Comment: And technically, while there is no functional difference between catalectic trochaic meter and acephaleous iambic meter (they both sound the same), this would be acephaleous iambic meter because the lines surrounding the first line are in iambic meter: see https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/catalectic-trochaic-tetrameter-or-acephaleous-iambic-tetrameter-scanning-kubla

Comment: @Hamlet I'm sorry but "Why doesn't Coleridge use trochaic meter for the line in his poem about trochees?" was your question I thought. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Hamlet The semicolon disassociates the first line from the second though, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not disputing the fact that the second line is referring to spondees, not trochees.

Comment: @Hamlet Why should the second line define what the meter is in the first line?

Comment: the second line does not define how the first line is read in terms of meter. **catalectic trochaic meter and acephaleous iambic meter sound exactly the same**. The second line simply defines the technical word for the meter of the first line.

Comment: it's the convention that most people use. There isn't any real meaning behind it, which makes sense, because again, there is no difference between catalectic trochaic meter and acephaleous iambic meter. See https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3091/111.

Comment: @Hamlet OK, sorry for the misunderstanding. What do I do with my answer now that you edited the question?

Comment: it's fine. I should have made the question clearer.

Comment: to be honest, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you continue the meter to the next line, you find it is unstressed (From), completing the trochee from the previous line's stressed syllable (short). Now, if you continue, you might find another problem with the ending of the second line, mainly that it is stressed. However, notice the next line, which starts discussing the spondee, two long stressed syllables. If you consider "sort" to be part of the first spondee, then you must consider "yet" to be the end of the last one, which allows "ill able" to be the first dactyl. The rest of the meters work out by line.

Trochee: **Tro**chee **trips** from **long** to **short**; From **long** to **long** in **so**lemn

Spondee: **sort** **Slow** **Spondee** **stalks**; **strong** **foot**! **yet**

Dactyl: **ill** able

Either that or it sounded better to Coleridge, and he wanted to confuse future generations.